# How do I increase time of slide in jcarousel?

Tags: views

I want to increase the timer of the slide by 4 seconds so that each slide should be visible for 4 seconds. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Click on "*View Transition Advanced Options*" and into "*Timer delay*" set time in milliseconds as shown in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of auto according to your time

```
$('#jcarousel').jcarousel({
  auto: 3, //delay 3 seconds
  wrap: 'circular',
  animation: 1000,
  scroll: 1
});
```